# Reading data only once and apply same function for different variables

Tags: r, pca

Dataset I am working on looks like-[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsIqM.png) there are 6 different countries and r_1..r_13 specifies the reasons. I want to apply PCA on this dataset to find out the significant reasons for each country 
The question I want to ask is how can I run PCA for each country without reading file for each country instead I want to read the entire file as shown above.
Also please check the code I am using for doing PCA-

```
    pca<-prcomp(numeric,center=T,scale=T)
    summary(pca)
    eigen_val<-pca$sdev ^2
    sum(eigen_val)
    prop_var<-round(eigen_val/sum(eigen_val),4)
    round(sum(prop_var[1:13]),4)
    load<-pca$rotation
```

After computing rotation matrix I will check which PC's are most correlated with which observed variables and accordingly I will decide the significance of the variables.(on the basis of- more than no. of PC's correlated with variable more is the significance of the variable)
Kindly suggest whether the approach is correct or not !
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. This question is short on details (code and data). Please take a look at these tips on creating a [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That being said, gregor's post on [working with a list of data.frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) gives the R best practices using `split` and `lapply` to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple starting point for a solution that you can tweak to get the results in your desired format. Let's assume you're working with the `iris` dataset in `R`, and you want to do `pca` for each `Species`, kind of like how you want to do `pca` by each country in your data.

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
Iris <- split(iris, iris$Species)
for(i in 1:length(Iris)){
  assign(paste0("pca", i), prcomp(Iris[[i]][which(names(iris)!="Species")], center=T, scale.=T))
}
```

Comment: Thanks alott Gaurav!! Can you please suggest whether my approach is correct or not ? Also how can I save the results of for loop instead  of printing it on screen and how can I compute top 6 and bottom most related elements from the rotations matrix of each country/Species.

Comment: It seems like your approach is fine. I edited my code above to store `pca` instead of printing it. You can use the same `assign` approach to do more computations inside the `for` loop and store them in variables. To see the most important elements of the rotations, you can use the `summary` command. This link might help with the details: http://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/

Comment: Can Someone suggest if I am working on various files stored in a list then how can I split those files country wise(Variable wise).